# Is there a better way to align this background image with the text above it?

Tags: css

I'm trying to align a background image (gray circles on the right) to the text above it using multiple media queries but I'm not having much success. I could make a bunch more media queries but **I just wondered if there was a smarter, more automated way to do this**.

Here's the page: https://veritywebsvs.com/wmjw/
I need to get the gray circles on the right to be centered with the text above it as stated before already.

Here's the CSS I'm using to try to center the circle:

```
#hero .fl-node-60bfc0dd0afeb > .fl-row-content-wrap {
    background-image: url(circles-2-gray-trans.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    border-width: 0;
    background-clip: border-box;
    min-height: 650px;
}
#hero > .fl-row-content-wrap {
    background-size: 60vw;
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
    #hero > .fl-row-content-wrap {
        background-position: 95% center;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
    #hero > .fl-row-content-wrap {
        background-position: 110% center;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1099px) {
    #hero > .fl-row-content-wrap {
        background-position: 120% center;
        background-size: 75vw;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    #hero > .fl-row-content-wrap {
        background-position: 130% center;
        background-size: 80vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try making the div of the text circular and align in with the picture behind it.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Give a border radius of 50%. Then add sufficient padding. Then align the circle using position absolute and top and right props of css

Comment: you could have posted your css for this background image and defined your description only on the alignment of the image. instead , you wrote the whole story and there is nothing in your question that is helpful or understandable. please correct correct your question as soon as possible.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the code after I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using background image and trying to get the image to right position, use `<img>` and position it wherever you want with help of negative margins if you use `position: relative`, or you can use `top, bottom, right, left positioning` if you use `position: absolute`. along with that use `z-index` to layer the image properly.

Add a div and img like i have added here, it will solve your immediate issue of positioning.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

```css
.for-bg {
  width: 1080px;
  margin-top: -1050px;
  max-width: revert;
  right: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-right: -300px;
  margin-bottom: -630px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fl-module fl-module-rich-text fl-node-60c015378acf7" data-node="60c015378acf7">
  <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
    <div class="fl-rich-text">
      <p>WMJW has been serving clients<br>
        <span style="color: #ca9130;">for ___ years</span><br> and ________.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div><img src="https://veritywebsvs.com/wmjw/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/circles-2-gray-trans.svg" class="for-bg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
1. I tried it with relative positioning but the image cannot be sized large than its parent unless set to absolute positioning. 
2. With absolute positioning, I still have to create multiple media queries for various screen sizes. 
3. I tried the following but still need multiple media queries 
` .for-bg { Width: 1080px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; top: -27vh; right: 2vw; z-index: 0; }` 
4. I finally resolved the issue by making the text part of the image since it's an SVG. 
Thanks again!